# Possibility to cancel Observable in Angular 2 typescript with a button click and trigger a new one

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have three buttons in my UI. Each Button would trigger an Observable to a different backend server endpoint.

For example:

1. Button 1 : HTTP GET Observable to https://endpoint1.something?params=whatever
2. Button 2:  HTTP GET Observable to https://endpoint2.something?params=whatever

..

#### Description

[image: basicUI]

Each of the Blue buttons would need to trigger three different Endpoints and would provide user some autocompletion below the input box after clicking the respective button (instance, when `hasProperty` button is clicked `<hasProperty>` is shown and any suggestions are show below).
[image: autocompletion]

#### Problem

After I select for example `hasSeatBelt`and then go ahead to click the `hasValue` button I still get Suggestions from the previous `hasProperty` Observable
[image: Problem]

Is there any way to **Cancel the Previous Observable** when on clicks on the other Buttons?

---

### Code Snippets

**`component.html`** (input box + `<code></code>` + space for Observable data)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h5>Your Semantic Query</h5>
            <code>
                {{sentence | json}}
            </code>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <input type="search" class="form-control"
                           [(ngModel)] = "sentence"
                           [formControl]="searchField"
                           (keydown)="selected = false; true;"
                    #searchbox style="width: 500px;">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="lead" *ngIf="loading">Loading...</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group ac-keywords" *ngIf="searchField.value !== '' && !selected">
                <li class="list-group-item"
                    *ngFor="let eachProp of results | async" (click)="searchbox.value = eachProp.translated; selected=true; sentence=sentence+eachProp.translated;"
                >
                    {{eachProp.translated}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`component.html` (button) area

```
<div class="btn-group">
                    <li>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                                (click)="hasPropertyRelation('hasProperty')"> hasProperty </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                                (click)="hasValueRelation('hasValue')"> hasValue </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" #refBtn
                                (click)="hasReferenceRelation('hasReference')"> hasReference </button>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngFor="let eachButton of objectRelationsButton['listOfSQP']">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" #objBtn (click)="objectPropRelation(eachButton)">
                            {{eachButton}}
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </div>]
```

**`component.ts`**

```
    private loading: boolean = false;
    public objectRelationsButton: Object = {};
    public sentence: any;
    private results: Observable<SearchItem[]>;
    private searchField: FormControl;
    selected: boolean = false;
    @Input() configSPQ: Object;
    @Input() lang: string;
    constructor(private backendCall: backednCallService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.searchField = new FormControl();
        // get the yellow buttons from server..
        let dummyJSON = this.configSPQ;
        this.backendCall.getSQPButton(dummyJSON)
            .then(res => this.objectRelationsButton = res);
        this.sentence = this.configSPQ['frozenConcept'];
    }

    // Blue hasProperty Button
    hasPropertyRelation(inputVal: string) {
       // add text dynamically
       this.sentence += ' <' + inputVal + '> ';
        // HTTP Observable
        this.results = this.searchField.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .do( _ => this.loading = true)
            .switchMap(term =>
                this.expSearch.searchForProperty(this.configSPQ)
            )
            .do( _ => this.loading = false);
    }
         
    // hasValue Blue Button
    hasValueRelation(inputVal: string) {
        // CANCEL PREVIOUS OBSERVABLE MAYBE HERE
        this.sentence += ' <' + inputVal + '> ';
    }

    hasReferenceRelation(inputVal: string) {
        this.sentence += ' <' + inputVal + '> ';
    }

    objectPropRelation(inputVal: string) {
        this.sentence += ' <' + inputVal + '> ';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you emit to `.switchMap` it will cancel the previous http observable if you emit a new value. There are a few different ways you could do this, and I would do it by merging the `valueChanges` observable with an observable you can emit a value to and then switchMap and subscribe to that.

```
results$ = this.searchField.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).distinctUntilChanged();
cancel$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

...
this.results = this.results$.merge(this.cancel$).do(() => this.loading = true)
  .switchMap(term => {
    if (term) {
      return this.expSearch.searchForProperty(this.configSPQ);
    }
    return of();
  })
  .do(() => this.loading = false);
```

Then in the other buttons, you can do `this.cancel$.next(false)` in order to cancel the current http search.

Comment: I get an error `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.` which might be caused by the `BehaviourSubject`. Also are `results$` and `cancel$` local variables within each Button's method since you mention `cancel$` once and `this.cancel$` in your answer.

Comment: also I noticed that removing the `(keydown)='selected=false; true;'` did not provide me the the Observable for the next button press.

Comment: Sorry there should be `this.` in front of the class properties